# React onClick event suppressed while dropdown is open

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, react-hooks

I have created a codesandbox to demonstrate the problem:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-wu-mibxl

For some reason the onClick event handler on the link that comes after the dropdown, is not triggered while the dropdown is open and I have no idea why. I hope you can help me out here.

Comment: when i comment out `useOnClickOutside(ref, close)` it's working.

Comment: The issue is you are attaching event listener `mousedown` with document. If instead of mouse you use enter it is working fine.

Comment: @uday That breaks functionality of the dropdown component

Comment: @tarzenchugh How to make it work while still listening for mouse clicks outside the dropdown component?

Comment: In you're `useOnClickOutside` hook replace `mousedown` event with `enter`

Comment: replace `mousedown` by `mouseup`, its working for me.

Comment: Replacing it with either `mouseup` or `click` would work, but it would change the functionality a bit. Is it really not possible to use mousedown event and why?

Comment: mousedown event happens a lot before the click / mouseup usually (>50ms) and in this case the dom has changed and the element that you clicked is not in the place where you started the clicking (mousedown) and does not receive the click event. You could add a timeout to the useOnClickOutside cb call but that is very unreliable.

Comment: @Absor can you repost your comment as an answer please so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mousedown event happens a lot before the click / mouseup usually (>50ms) and in this case the dom has changed and the element that you clicked is not in the place where you started the clicking (mousedown) and does not receive the click event. You could add a timeout to the useOnClickOutside cb call but that is very unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is a single threaded language. So to get the `<Dropdown>` list to close, you need to close the `alert()` box first. The closest you will get is the work around in the comments, or you can change the action of clicking the link to `OnMouseUp` rather than `OnClick`. Either way, you will still need to close the alert box for execution to continue.

Comment: The dropdown list closes just fine, it's the link followed by the <Dropdown> that fails to trigger it's onClick listener while the dropdown is open. Alerts are there for testing the onClick handlers. You could replace all alerts with console.log and the problem would be still there.

Comment: That is because the action to fire the alert() is after you release the click. However, the link moves as soon as you mouse down preventing you from being able to finish click the link, if that makes sense.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-chaplygin-itibo
Is this your desired outcome?
I added an ID to the bottom link, and changed the CSS so the clickable area of the link continues another 15% past the visible text.

Comment: After reading Absor's comment above and your follow-up comment, I understand what you're saying now. While your answer is correct, Absor's is much more clear.

Comment: Yes sorry about that, my explanation did seem a bit convoluted to begin with.